# Scraper Python and YouTube API "raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None"

Tags: python, json, api, web-scraping, youtube

would like to scrap youtube for some channels stats and lo learn how it works. And than to make csv for the following analysis. Used this video to create and to learn.

I have 2 files: main.py, youtube_statistics.py

**main.py**

```
 from youtube_statistics import YTstats

API_KEY = "xxx"
channel_id = "xxx"

yt = YTstats(API_KEY, channel_id)
yt.get_channel_statistics()
yt.get_channel_video_data()
yt.dump()
# yt.get_channel_video_data()
```

**youtube_statistics.py**

```
import requests
import json
from tqdm import tqdm

class YTstats:
    def __init__(self, api_key, channel_id):
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.channel_id = channel_id
        self.channel_statistics = None
        self.video_data = None


    def get_channel_statistics(self):
        url = f'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id={self.channel_id}&key={self.api_key}'
        json_url = requests.get(url)
        data = json.loads(json_url.text)
        print(data)
        try:
            data = data["items"][0]
        except:
            data = None

        self.channel_statistics = data
        return data

    def get_channel_video_data(self):
        # 1) get video ids
        channel_videos = self._get_channel_videos(limit=50)
        print(len(channel_videos))
        # 2) get video statistics
        parts = ["snippet", "statistics", "contentDetails"]
        for video_id in tqdm(channel_videos):
            for part in parts:
                data = self._get_single_video_data(video_id, part)
                channel_videos[video_id].update(data)

        self.video_data = channel_videos
        return channel_videos

    def _get_single_video_data(self, video_id, part):
        url = f"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/video?part={part}&id={video_id}&key={self.api_key}"
        json_url = requests.get(url)
        data = json.loads(json_url.text)
        try:
            data = data['items'][0][part]
        except:
            print('error')
            data = dict()

        return data

    def _get_channel_videos(self, limit=None):
        url = f"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={self.api_key}&channelId={self.channel_id}&part=id&order=date"
        if limit is not  None and isinstance(limit, int):
            url += "&maxResults=" + str(limit)

        vid, npt = self._get_channel_videos_per_page(url)
        idx = 0
        while(npt is not None and idx < 10):
            nexturl = url + "&pageToken=" + npt
            next_vid, npt = self._get_channel_videos_per_page(nexturl)
            vid.update(next_vid)
            idx += 1

        return vid

    def _get_channel_videos_per_page(self, url):
        json_url = requests.get(url)
        data = json.loads(json_url.text)
        channel_videos = dict()
        if 'items' not in data:
            return channel_videos, None

        item_data = data['items']
        nextPageToken = data.get("nextPageToken", None)
        for item in item_data:
            try:
                kind = item['id']['kind']
                if kind == 'youtube#video':
                    video_id = item['id']['videoId']
                    channel_videos[video_id] = dict()
            except KeyError:
                print("error")

        return channel_videos, nextPageToken

    def dump(self):
        if self.channel_statistics is None or self.video_data is None:
            print('data is none')
            return

        fused_data = {self.channel_id: {"channel_statistics": self.channel_statistics, "video_data": self.video_data}}

        channel_title = self.video_data.popitem()[1].get('channelTitle', self.channel_id)
        channel_title = "Eka" # TODO: get channel name from data
        channel_title = channel_title.replace(" ", "_").lower()
        file_name = channel_title + '.json'
        with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(fused_data, f, indent=4)

        print('file dumped')
```

Run is returning the error:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe "D:/!Python/YouTube API/main.py"
{'kind': 'youtube#channelListResponse', 'etag': 'z6Nyb5nqgDzJ-bV6OuApUUArIj0', 'pageInfo': {'totalResults': 1, 'resultsPerPage': 1}, 'items': [{'kind': 'youtube#channel', 'etag': 'gwHw77rKYZBqZcw7PlAfjA6AJ9o', 'id': 'UCL1rJ0ROIw9V1qFeIN0ZTZQ', 'statistics': {'viewCount': '30386664', 'commentCount': '0', 'subscriberCount': '244000', 'hiddenSubscriberCount': False, 'videoCount': '510'}}]}
446
  0%|          | 0/446 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/!Python/YouTube API/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    yt.get_channel_video_data()
  File "D:\!Python\YouTube API\youtube_statistics.py", line 34, in get_channel_video_data
    data = self._get_single_video_data(video_id, part)
  File "D:\!Python\YouTube API\youtube_statistics.py", line 43, in _get_single_video_data
    data = json.loads(json_url.text)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can't identify the solution. What have I do in this situation?
Thank you. Python ver. 3.8.2

Comment: small typo you have there. You are missing the "s" in `videos`. Also, you sure you want to be sharing you API key?

Comment: `url = f"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part={part}&id={video_id}&key={self.api_key}"` is where you were missing that "s"

Comment: Thank you so much!